# alertDialog from xml layout

Tags: android, xml

im tryin to retrieve radio button value and checkbox value from alertdialog. this alert is created from xml layout here my xml file (ard.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center" >

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/rardEtat"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rd_bien"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="Bien"
        android:checked="true"
        android:textSize="10pt" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rd_casse"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="Casse"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rd_bien"
        android:textSize="10pt" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rd_abs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rd_casse"
        android:text="Absente"
        android:textSize="10pt" />
</RadioGroup>

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checked"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/rardEtat"
    android:textSize="10pt"
    android:text="Brule"   />

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/etatProprete"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/checked" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rd_propre"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/checked"
        android:checked="true"
        android:text="Propre"
        android:textSize="10pt" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rd_sale"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rd_propre"
        android:text="Sale"
        android:textSize="10pt" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rd_tsale"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rd_sale"
        android:text="Trop sale"
        android:textSize="10pt" />
</RadioGroup>

</RelativeLayout>
```

here is my activity (button listner)

```
AlertDialog.Builder customDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View view2=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.ard,null);

RadioGroup radioGroupEtat=(RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rardEtat);
int radioetat = radioGroupEtat.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
RadioButton etatbut = (RadioButton) findViewById(radioetat);
String etatBac= etatbut.getText();

RadioGroup radioGroupProprete=(RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.etatProprete);
int radiopropre = radioGroupProprete.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
RadioButton propre = (RadioButton) findViewById(radiopropre);
String etatPropre=propre.getText();

CheckBox checkBrule=(CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checked);
customDialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){

@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

// show what i've checked ! 
}});

customDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){

@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

}});

customDialog.setView(view);

customDialog.show();
}
});
```

but im getting error in groupradio instanciation

```
RadioGroup radioGroupEtat=(RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rardEtat);
/* error here */    int radioetat = radioGroupEtat.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
```

Any help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you must replace:

```
RadioGroup radioGroupEtat=(RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rardEtat);
```

to

```
RadioGroup radioGroupEtat=(RadioGroup) view2.findViewById(R.id.rardEtat);
```

because you have to find your children views inside your inflated parent view, and your parent view for alert dialog is `view2`